What is the blue hue at the middle bottom of Lady Mergot Fenring's binocular vision?
In the movie, Dune Part 2, when Lady Mergot Fenring watches over the gladiators fighting, there is this blue hue at the middle bottom of her binocular vision, they almost look like characters, what is it? 

Maybe a readout display? A common feature of viewing devices in sci fi

Judging from the changes seen when it focuses on different places it looks like a range/distance indicator
